# Unmarshalling an xml element which is not part of namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring, namespaces, unmarshalling

I have an xml response coming from a webservice:

```
<ns2:response xmlns:ns2="http://abc.com">
  <ns2:msgHeader>
    <ns2:empid>1234</ns2:empid>
    <ns2:empname>John</ns2:empid>
  </ns2:msgHeader>
  <error>
    <httpstatus>500</httpstatus>
    <description>Error while processing the request.Please contact customercare</description>
  </error>
</ns2:response>
```

How do I unmarshall when the xml schema is in this format. `<error>` is part of the root element `<response>`.

I am using Restful client and using resttemplate to make the request to the server. My `applicationcontext.xml` uses `org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter` for marshalling and unmarshalling the request and response XMLs.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an xsd? I presume  element should be defined in your xsd

Answer (score 0):

presumably, you have a schema for the `response` element, where it has a reference to the `error` element, which is in a separate schema (unfortunately, schemas cannot have more than one namespace in the same file).  the separate schema file with the `error` element will have no targetNamespace.